# JVM getting crashed Frequently Because of Fatal Error: SIGSEGV (0xb)

Tags: java, jvm, segmentation-fault

I am getting the below error while the application is running. Could somebody help on this issue?

```
Jdk Version - 1.6.0_38

Jvm Crash Report:

########
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1de43e5eb1, pid=29722, tid=139766266042112

JRE version: 6.0_38-b05

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

Problematic frame:V  [libjvm.so+0x675eb1]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late_post(Node*)+0x121

###############################

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000401c7800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=29737, stack(0x00007f1dde939000,0x00007f1ddea3a000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000008
```

Comment: This must be a JVM bug that has been fixed already. JDK version you use is a way too old and is no longer supported. Consider updating JDK.

Comment: @apagin Thanks for your reply.There are serveral application modules running in one linux box pointing the same jdk. Only one application is crashing frequently.

Comment: The app may use a native library containing a bug.

Comment: The crashed thread is called "C2 CompilerThread0", so I'm thinking it can't be a native library bug. The only solution is to change the JRE with a version that doesn't have this problem.